# require.js passing in a model Object [object Object] has no method 'fetch'

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm getting an error in my view where var campaign = new CampaginModel() is not getting the model.

Using require.js + backbone:

**Error:**

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fetch'**

When I console out the object `console.log(CampaginModel)` I get `function (){return i.apply(this,arguments)}` which is completely incorrect as it should be an instance of the model.

What have I done wrong here?

**Model** (models/CampaginModel):

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

    var CampaginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
       urlRoot: '/api/v1/campaign/'
    });

  return CampaginModel;

});
```

**View:**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/RewardView',
  'views/FriendRewardView',
  'models/CampaginModel',
  'text!templates/backbone/portal/campaignTemplate.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, campaignTemplate, CampaginModel){


   var CampaginView = Backbone.View.extend({
       el: '#campaign-panel',
        render: function(options) {
            if(options.id){



                var campaign = new CampaginModel({id: options.id});

                campaign.fetch({
                    success: function(campaign){

                    }// end success
                }); // end fetch
            }// end if option.id
        } // end render function
    }); // end campagin view


  return CampaginView;

});
```

**main.js:**

```
require.config({

  shim: {


    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone',
      init: function (_, $) { Backbone.$ = $; return Backbone; }


    }
  },
  paths: {
    jquery: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min',
    underscore: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min',
    backbone: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min',
    templates: '/templates/'
  }

});

require([
  'app'
], function(App){

  App.initialize();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of the view is incorrect as you are defining seven parameters but passing just five to the function. So when you are instantiating `CampaginModel` what you really have is an instance of the view `views/FriendRewardView`. So change your definition as follows:

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'views/RewardView',
'views/FriendRewardView',
'models/CampaginModel',
'text!templates/backbone/portal/campaignTemplate.html'
 ], function($, _, Backbone, rewardView, friendRewardView, CampaginModel, campaignTemplate){

});
```

Cheers.

Comment: I don't understand why would I have an instance of FriendRewardView? I pass in that view because I may call it within CampaginView. could you explain many thanks

Comment: Because you have defined seven dependencies but passed just five of them to the function as arguments, so as these are assigned in order, your fifth dependency is `views/FriendRewardView` so it gets assigned to your fifth parameter which is `CampaginModel`.